# How do I get a token list with an end-of-line character in it?

Tags: verbatim, expl3, token-lists

The context of this question is that I have a command defined using `xparse` that slurps in a verbatim argument which can be long.  I want to do a replacement on the resulting token list, but the token that I want to replace is the new line character.  According to `\tl_show:n {#1}` this is `^^M`.  I'm having great difficulty in getting this into `\tl_replace_all:Nnn` to do the replacement.

If my token list happens to begin with `^^M` then I can slurp it from there and use that.  So I know that it works if I can just get the `^^M` character into a token list.  But I don't see how to get it in without this hack.

Here's a minimum sort of working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn {NV}

\NewDocumentCommand \getstuff {+v}
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl {\tl_head:N \l_tmpa_tl}
  \tl_replace_all:NVn \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl {!wibble!}
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\getstuff+
some stuff
+

\getstuff+some stuff+

\end{document}
```

Comment: In order to better understand what a token list contains, you can use `\tl_show_analysis:n`, which requires `\usepackage{l3tl-analysis}`. You'll see `^^M (the character ^^M)` which means `^^M` with category code 12.

Comment: @LoopSpace Hi, this is just to call you, in case you want to answer a question of mine http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196498/unlimited-size-delimiters-with-tikz with, e.g., `calligraphic curved parenthesis` from your `spath3` package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help of `\tl_analysis_show:n` you can get a better result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn {NV}

\str_const:Nx \c_other_eol_str { \cs_to_str:N \^^M }

\NewDocumentCommand \getstuff {+v}
 {
  \tl_analysis_show:n { #1 } % for debugging
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
  \tl_replace_all:NVn \l_tmpa_tl \c_other_eol_str {!wibble!}
  \tl_analysis_show:N \l_tmpa_tl % for debugging
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\getstuff+
some stuff
+

\getstuff+some stuff+

\end{document}
```

The log has, for the first call of `\getstuff`,

```
The token list contains the tokens:
>  ^^M (the character ^^M)
>  s (the character s)
>  o (the character o)
>  m (the character m)
>  e (the character e)
>    (blank space  )
>  s (the character s)
>  t (the character t)
>  u (the character u)
>  f (the character f)
>  f (the character f)
>  ^^M (the character ^^M).
```

This confirms that `^^M` has been absorbed as a token with category code 12; since `\c_other_eol_str` contains exactly a token with the same property, the next diagnostic message says

```
The token list \l_tmpa_tl contains the tokens:
>  ! (the character !)
>  w (the letter w)
>  i (the letter i)
>  b (the letter b)
>  b (the letter b)
>  l (the letter l)
>  e (the letter e)
>  ! (the character !)
>  s (the character s)
>  o (the character o)
>  m (the character m)
>  e (the character e)
>    (blank space  )
>  s (the character s)
>  t (the character t)
>  u (the character u)
>  f (the character f)
>  f (the character f)
>  ! (the character !)
>  w (the letter w)
>  i (the letter i)
>  b (the letter b)
>  b (the letter b)
>  l (the letter l)
>  e (the letter e)
>  ! (the character !).
```

Hurray! The `^^M` has been correctly recognized and changed into `!wibble!`.

A different strategy is by using `l3regex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \getstuff {+v}
 {
  \tl_analysis_show:n { #1 } % for debugging
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \r } { !wibble! } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_analysis_show:N \l_tmpa_tl % for debugging
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\getstuff+
some stuff
+

\getstuff+some stuff+

\end{document}
```

In this case `!wibble!` will be all with category code 12 characters in the modified token list; but of course you don't really want to change `^^M` into `!wibble!`, do you?

Comment: Just to clarify, in my actual case then I wanted to replace `^^M` by a macro so, no, `!wibble!` was not the desired outcome.  (To complete the reference, the `!` are symbolic of pencils.)

Comment: @AndrewStacey If you want to replace `^^M` with the macro `\foo`  with `\regex_replace_all:nnN`, say `{\c{foo}}` in the second argument, instead of `{!wibble!}`.

Comment: Useful to know.  In *this* case, `\tl_replace_all:NVn` is sufficient to my needs so I shan't load `l3regex`.  But as always it's good to see examples of these more advanced tools.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work

```
{\char_set_catcode_other:N \^^M\tl_gset:Nn\g_tmpa_tl{^^M}}
```